# Why are we allowed to pull out a nonconstant from the inner product? Laplacian on Manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~canzani/math253/Lecture7.pdf)

> [image]

In where it says,

> we get $\sum_{m = 1} a_mg_{mi} = \partial \phi/\partial x_i$.

I know they did $<a_i \partial/\partial_{x_i}, \partial/\partial_{x_j}>$, but isn't this implying that $<a_i \partial/\partial_{x_i}, \partial/\partial_{x_j}> = a_i< \partial/\partial_{x_i}, \partial/\partial_{x_j}>$. I thought $a_i$ are functions are not numbers.

Comment: You have an inner product for every point $p$ of $M$. Pointwise, you are pulling out $a_i(p)$, which is a number.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.

Comment: @Zircht You should make that an answer.